# Deploy Docker Image from DockerHub as App via Terrafiom

Tags: terraform, digital-ocean, dockerhub

I'm trying to deploy an App via Terraform. I want to use one of my public Images from DockerHub.

The DigitalOcean Provider works (confirmed that with an other PoC).

Now I want to deploy a Docker image as an App. I found the digitalocean_app resource (https://registry.terraform.io/providers/digitalocean/digitalocean/latest/docs/resources/app). The docs state, that I have to set "registry_type" to one of DOCR (DigitalOcean container registry) or DOCKER_HUB.

But I don't really know how. This is my config.

```
resource "digitalocean_app" "docs-page-docker-app" {
  spec {
    name   = "docs-page-docker-app"
    region = "fra1"

    # domain

    service {
      name      = "docs-page-docker-app-image"
      http_port = 3000

      image {
        registry_type = "DOCKER_HUB"
        repository    = "sommerfeldio/docs-website"
        tag           = "stable"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I put DOCKER_HUB in quotation marks ("), I always get the error "Image does not exist or is private". When I remove the quotation marks, my config is no longer valid.

From the docs I don't really get how I have to specify that I want to use DockerHub as container registry. Anyone got an Idea on how I could tackle this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to reverse-engineer the App deployment. I created a Docker App with an image from DockerHub via the WebUI and used `terraform import` to get the terraform config. Deployment works now.

Now I’m running into some DNS issues, but this might be better in a separate question.

This is the config that allows the deployment of an image from DockerHub to the DigitalOcean App platform:

```
resource "digitalocean_app" "docs-page" {
  spec {
    domains = [
      "${digitalocean_record.CNAME-docs.name}.${digitalocean_domain.cloud.name}",
    ]
    name   = "docs-page"
    region = var.do_region

    service {
      name               = "docs-page-app"
      http_port          = 80
      instance_count     = 1
      instance_size_slug = var.do_instance_smallest
      internal_ports     = []
      #name               = "docs-page-app"
      source_dir = "/"

      image {
        registry_type = "DOCKER_HUB"
        registry      = "sommerfeldio"
        repository    = "docs-website"
        tag           = "stable"
      }

      routes {
        path                 = "/"
        preserve_path_prefix = false
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "digitalocean_domain" "cloud" {
  name = var.do_base_domain
}

resource "digitalocean_record" "CNAME-docs" {
  domain = digitalocean_domain.cloud.name
  type   = "CNAME"
  name   = "docs"
  value  = "@"
}
```